# Salesforce Email Send as Trigger in Process Builder

Tags: trigger, email, process-builder, tasks, activityhistory

Wondering if it is possible to update a lead's status to "Contacted" after an email is sent.

[image: The message is being sent from the "Activity History" section on the lead's page]

I have set up a process that updates the lead status every time a completed task is created or edited (which works UNLESS the completed task is an email being created in this manner). Looks like that type of task [won't](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147584/using-process-builder-to-react-to-new-email-being-sent-from-account) trigger anything in the process builder. I'm wondering if there is a workaround.

When I click on the email I see that it is a different type of object:
[image]

But I can't get the leadID from this object...nothing relevant appears in the "Related to" list. Is there a way to link this object to a record id in the process builder? Or is there a work around to get this type of process to respond to "internal workflows"?

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround. For anyone who is curious:

1. Set up a flow (Setup--> type Flows --> New Flow)
2. create 2 variables (`varToEmailAddress` and `varLeadID`)
   NOTE: make sure both of these are set to input and output, don't leave as private.
3. Create a Record lookup on Lead object Where email = varToEmailAddress. Save the lead's Id to varLeadID.
4. Create a record update step. Filter for lead id = varleadID, set status to contacted.

From within process builder: 
1. Use 'Email Message' as the object type to trigger your process, and Choose "Flow" as the type of action to be taken.

2. Select the flow created and pass in the ToAddress field from the email message to the variable varEmailAddress